# Iris dataset not showing "Species" column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, iris-dataset

I am working with numpy and pandas on Python to learn how to work on dataframes.

I'm coding on Collaboratory and I have loaded the Iris dataset but for some reason, there is no "Species" column in my dataframe. Maybe I've loaded it in an incorrect fashion? I'd appreciate help on the matter.

I added an image, if the code is still needed then this is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

df = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, columns=load_iris().feature_names)
```

[image]

Comment: See more information abouth the dataset here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html#iris-dataset. It seems that the species is the y column in the dataset which can be called by: load_iris().target

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                  columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target']).astype({'target': int}) \
       .assign(species=lambda x: x['target'].map(dict(enumerate(iris['target_names']))))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  target    species
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2       0     setosa
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2       0     setosa
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2       0     setosa
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2       0     setosa
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2       0     setosa
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...     ...        ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3       2  virginica
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9       2  virginica
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0       2  virginica
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3       2  virginica
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8       2  virginica

[150 rows x 6 columns]
```

How to create the `species` column from `target` and `target_names` columns?

```
>>> iris['target_names']
array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
# index 0: setosa
# index 1: versicolor
# index 2: virginica

>>> iris['target']
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

You just need a dict mapping to replace 0 by 'setosa', 1 by 'versicolor' and 2 by 'virginica'. Use `enumerate` to create a list of tuples `[(0, 'setosa'), (1, 'versicolor), (2, 'virginica')] then` dict` to convert as a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(iris['target_names']))
{0: 'setosa', 1: 'versicolor', 2: 'virginica'}
```

Now `Series.map` will map the corresponding values:

```
>>> df['target'].map(dict(enumerate(iris['target_names'])))
0         setosa
1         setosa
2         setosa
3         setosa
4         setosa
         ...    
145    virginica
146    virginica
147    virginica
148    virginica
149    virginica
Name: target, Length: 150, dtype: object
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you maybe explain the parameters you added, please? If it's too much of a bother then I'll try to find out myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chefi. I updated my answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you again and sorry for the late response. (I don't visit stackoverflow very often)