# creating training.csv and test.csv file after splitting a dataset using sklearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, split

I am working on iris dataset. I was able to split the dataset with training and test set.

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = .3, random_state = 50)
```

Now I want to extract two individual csv files one for training dataset and another one for test dataset.

training_set.csv will contain X_train and Y_train.

test_set.csv will contain X_test and Y_test.

I have tried this code block

```
training_set = pd.DataFrame(X_train, Y_train)
```

Which retured

```
   sepal.width  petal.length    petal.width
   variety          
   Setosa   NaN NaN NaN
   Setosa   NaN NaN NaN
   Setosa   NaN NaN NaN
   Virginica    NaN NaN NaN
   Virginica    NaN NaN NaN
   ...  ... ... ...
  Versicolor    NaN NaN NaN
  Virginica NaN NaN NaN
  Setosa    NaN NaN NaN
  Virginica NaN NaN NaN
  Virginica NaN NaN NaN
   105 rows × 3 columns
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822068/15239951), load the dataset and convert it to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                  columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target']).astype({'target': int}) \
       .assign(species=lambda x: x['target'].map(dict(enumerate(iris['target_names']))))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(df.iloc[:, :4], df['species'], test_size=.3, random_state=50)

training_set = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
test_set = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)

training_set.to_csv('training.csv', index=False)
test_set.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Note: you can use `target` (int) or `species` (str) column as `y` vector.

Comment: If I save the data set as training.csv and test.csv I also got a column for index. How could I get rid of this column?

Comment: Use `index=False`. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you trying to save the test and training dataset into a csv. is that correct?

did you try this and it doesn't work?

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train, Y_train).to_csv('training.csv')
```

OR

```
training_set.to_csv('training.csv')
```