# How do I load a excel file from my system in ScitKit for train and test

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How do I load a excel file from my system in SciKit for train and test.

I tried pandas for importing, i was able to import it using

`data=pd.read_excel("IRIS.xlsx")`

`print(data.head())`
but then am not able to perform this line
`X,y=data(return_X_y=True)`
giving me a dataframe error.
what should i do or import before this line so i am able to carry out train and test successfully
[code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7fMm.png)

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a pandas Dataframe and it does not have any method `return_X_y=True`. This is only present in most `sklearn` load data functions e.g. `sklearn.datasets.load_XXX```.

In your case you load the data manually thus, you just need to slice and select the desired columns.

```
y = data["target"].values

# select all columns except the target
X = data.loc[:, data.columns != "target"].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.iloc`:

```
data = pd.read_excel('IRIS.xlsx')
X, y = data.iloc[:, :-1], data.iloc[-1]
```

If you really want to use `iris` dataset, use `sklearn` directly:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris['data'], iris['target']
```

Comment: More processing on this dataframe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822068/15239951)

Comment: when I try to get the length of y it returns 5, instead of 150. I think it is a matter of slicing so can you help me with it?

Comment: Is it the same for `len(X)`?

Comment: it gives a key error then for X

Comment: Do you use the method with `.iloc` or do you load dataset from `sklearn`? Please provide the output of `print(data.head())`

Comment: I am using  `.iloc`, it is returning the right data but for only 5 rows.

Comment: In your code above, do you have something like `data = data.head()`?

Comment: no, but i added and it had no changes ,still the same thing.

Comment: Can you share your file?